# $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] does not print unicode values as it is

Tags: php, unicode

`http://localhost/fw/api/fw_api.php?rule=unicode&action=create&phrase=යුනිකෝඩ්`

I accessing the above url. In `fw_api.php`, when I echo the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` it does not give the actual value of my Unicode phrase value "යුනිකෝඩ්" as in the URL. Is there any fix for this or am I doing/expecting something wrong here? Need help.

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo $_GET['phrase'];
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
die;
```

**Actual Result:**

යුනිකෝඩ්

rule=unicode&action=create&phrase=%E0%B6%BA%E0%B7%94%E0%B6%B1%E0%B7%92%E0%B6%9A%E0%B7%9D%E0%B6%A9%E0%B7%8A

**What I expected**

යුනිකෝඩ්

rule=unicode&action=create&phrase=යුනිකෝඩ්

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *actual* value is *actually* "%E0%B6%BA%E0%B7%94%E0..."!

URLs must consist of a subset of ASCII, they cannot contain other "Unicode characters". Your browser may be so nice as to let you input arbitrary Unicode characters and actually display them as characters, but behind the scenes the URL value is *percent encoded*. You'll have to decode it with [`rawurldecode`](http://php.net/rawurldecode).

The query string is automatically being parsed and decoded by PHP and placed in the `$_GET` array (and `$_POST` for the request body). But the raw query string you'll have to parse and decode yourself.

Comment: "rawurldecode" solved my problem. And I got your point too. Thank you very much.

Comment: Works as charm!

Answer (score 0):

1. Encode a value with special characters.

   ```
   $token = "a{l@3a3s9a";
   rawurlencode($token);   //The coding would be "%7Bl%403a3s9a"
   ```
2. Send the encoded value to the database
3. Receive the parameter value by URL

   ```
   $body = file_get_contents("php://input");
   if ($body == null && isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
       parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $this->parameters);
       return;
   }
   ```

   The parameter values are automatically decoded with `parse_str ()` without the need to use `rawurldecode()`
4. Use the value obtained by URL (`"a{l@3a3s9a"`)

> This encoding would be used to obtain special characters through a URL segment.

GL